# Problem understanding Importer Protocol in Python

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble understanding the Importer Protocol as per http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/. Should the `fullname` argument of `finder.find_module(fullname, path=None)` **never** include a . (dot)?

That is, if you want to find module `abc.efg.hij`, you must call `finder.find_module('hij', path='abc.efg')`. Calling `finder.find_module('abc.efg.hij')` would be **absolutely incorrect**.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is just saying that `import abc.efg.hij` will eventually result in 3 different `find_module` calls at various stages of the import process:

```
find_module("abc", None)
find_module("abc.efg", abc.__path__)
find_module("abc.efg.hij", abc.efg.__path__)
```

Exploring the importlib documentation may also be of interest to you:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/importlib#importlib.abc.Finder.find_module

Comment: Does this mean that the call `find_module('abc.efg.hij')` is still incorrect, because the `path` argument wasn't provided?

Comment: Yeah, the exact result of doing that will depend on the behaviour of the importers involved. `import` is unfortunately one of the murkiest and most poorly documented parts of the interpreter semantics.